# Keyboard and mouse not working after dual boot OS switch

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard, bluetooth

I have a dual boot setup, Windows 10 and Ubuntu. They are on separate SSDs on my laptop. I hibernate them before switching to another OS. If I do it consecutively, I will have no problems on my boot. But if its a couple of hours between, I am not able to use my keyboard and mouse after boot up on Ubuntu, even my laptop's own keyboard. The touchpad works though.

I've seen a similar issue that I have to disable xHCI on BIOS to make it work, but sadly, my laptop only comes with USB 3.0. I have a bluetooth keyboard and I noticed that at that time, the bluetooth is also off, but when I boot fresh, it recognizes the bluetooth keyboard immediately. I really need your help cause I have to use this laptop on hibernate dual boot.

*Edit: I think this only happens whenever a usb device is connected to the laptop on boot.

```
csi_handle_connector_change: ACK failed (-110)
usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
usb 2-1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
```

Comment: You are causing a problem. If you hibernate the Windows OS instead of a proper full shut down it can leave some hardware in a locked type state. Shut it down properly and test.

Comment: What would be the problem if I hibernate them if they are in different physical drives? not partitions

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

Windows/BIOS **fast boot** and **hibernation** can cause similar problems. Check your BIOS, and do this in Windows:

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

Comment: sorry, this did not work for me. my work around was that i never hibernated my windows and did not plug in my hub every time i switch OS

Comment: @Jann re: *"never hibernated my Windows"* sounds like my answer should have solved that. Did you do **both** parts of my answer?